# locate_template function - File not getting included

Tags: include, template-include

```
$locate = locate_template( 'widgets/the-post-widget.php' );
```

I am using the above path and method to include a file in `functions.php`, but that is not happening.

The file doesn't seem to include. Am I doing a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`locate_template` just returns the filename of the template. If you want to load the template, set the second argument to `true`:

```
locate_template( 'widgets/the-post-widget.php', true );
```